# Migrating From MS SQL Server 2008 to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have been put in charge of migrating the data out of an MS SQL Server 2008 database into MySQL. I have installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, have started the SQL Server and SQL Server Browser services, have enabled the TCP/IP and Named Pipes protocols for the sql database via the SQL Server Configuration Manager, and created a user with access via SQL Authentication instead of Windows Authentication. I am trying to get the data out using MySQL Migration Tool. When I try to connect to the server I get the following error:

```
Connecting to source database and retrieve schemata names.
Initializing JDBC driver ...  Driver class MS SQL JDBC Driver Opening
connection ...  Connection
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ukoff032/sqlexpress:1433/DbMain;user=remoteAccess;password=password;charset=utf-8;domain=
The list of schema names could not be retrieved (error: 0).
ReverseEngineeringMssql.getSchemata :Network error IOException:
Connection refused: connect Details: 
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:372)
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.<init>(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:178)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
com.mysql.grt.modules.ReverseEngineeringGeneric.establishConnection(ReverseEngineeringGeneric.java:141)
com.mysql.grt.modules.ReverseEngineeringMssql.getSchemata(ReverseEngineeringMssql.java:99)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
com.mysql.grt.Grt.callModuleFunction(Unknown Source)
```

I have also attempted to add the MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver so that I can export the data from SSMS but the driver does not appear in the export wizard's Destination options.

Can someone help me either get the MySQL ODBC Driver to show up in the SSMS export wizard destination options, or get MySQL Migration Tool to connect to the database and grab the data?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974755/migrate-database-from-sql-server-2008-to-mysql ? Possible duplicate?

Comment: I've seen a dozen of these questions on SO and tried everything suggested (is why there's a bumf of things I've tried at the top of the page). I had not seen this one. I am downloading the program now. Will update you if it works.

Comment: @Ocaso Protal: Have installed the software and managed to transfer the schema only. For some reason the software does not want to copy over the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the [SQL Examiner Suite](http://www.sqlaccessories.com/SQL_Examiner_Suite/). At first it did not work but after some digging found that the SQL being generated contained double-quotes around table names and columns (invalid SQL, basically). It does allow the user to edit the SQL before it is run so I had to go through the ~15 tables and delete the double-quotes around everything. Anywho - it works!!! Yay!

Answer (score 2):

Try Data Import tool (ODBC format) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/); or Data Export tool (ODBC format) in [dbForge Data Studio for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/datastudio/).

Comment: Worked like a charm on the 30 day trial! Thumbs up to dbForge as well.